# How to use jdb commands correctly if there exist multiple classes with the same full class name?

Tags: java, classloader, jdb

First, It is possible to have two classes with the same full class name in a single JVM.
It can be done with custom classloaders, just like what tomcat did. 
But the question now is how am I supposed to use jdb against it?

When I use `redefine MyClass MyClass.class`, it says "More than one class named: 'MyClass '".

Other commands have similar problems. For example the command `stop at <class>:<line>` sets a breadpoint at some line but I have no idea at which class the breakpoint is set!

Comment: Have you tried with fully qualified class name (i.e. mypackage.MyClass)?